# Is it possible to post to telegra.ph straight from a Telegram chat?

Tags: telegram

In addition to having a cloud messenger platform, Telegram also has a blogging site called telegra.ph. It's comparable to Medium or WordPress in functionality, and uses the Telegram account as the account for posting. It's possible to log in to this account by chatting with the bot account @telegraph, but as far as I could see, the actual creation and editing of posts can only be done in a web browser.

Is it possible to post to telegra.ph straight from the chat interface? I couldn't find how to do it, but maybe I didn't look well enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to do what you asked http://telegra.ph/api

Comment: Sure, I just wondered whether anybody have made such a bit already.

Answer (score 0):

Chat can be sent directly to telegra.ph or tgraph.io/api using api.telegra.ph or tgraph.io/api.
If you want, I will provide you with the API I created to make it easier for you to do this in python programming language.

```
import json
MAIN_URL = 'https://api.telegra.ph/'

class apiuz():
    def __init__(self):
        self.http = requests.Session()

    def callMethod(self, n_method=None, a_method=None):
        xitoy2= MAIN_URL + n_method.__name__+'?'
        for x,y in a_method:
            if x!='self' and y!=None: xitoy2+=x+'='+str(y)+'&'
        response = self.http.get(xitoy2[:-1])
        xitoy2 = eval(response.text.replace('\/','/').replace('true','True').replace('false','False'))
        return xitoy2 

        #Methods created by @apiuz
    def createAccount(self, short_name=None, author_name=None, author_url=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.createAccount, a_method=locals().items())

    def editAccountInfo(self, access_token=None, short_name=None, author_name=None, author_url=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.editAccountInfo, a_method=locals().items())

    def getAccountInfo(self, access_token=None, field=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.getAccountInfo, a_method=locals().items())

    def revokeAccessToken(self, access_token=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.revokeAccessToken, a_method=locals().items())

    def createPage(self, access_token=None, title=None, author_name=None, author_url=None,
        content=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.createPage, a_method=locals().items())

    def editPage(self, access_token=None, path=None, title=None, content=None,
        author_name=None, author_url=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.editPage, a_method=locals().items())

    def getPage(self, path=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.getPage, a_method=locals().items())

    def getPageList(self, access_token=None, offset=0, limit=50):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.getPageList, a_method=locals().items())

    def getViews(self, path=None, year=None, month=None, day=None, hour=None):
        return self.callMethod(n_method=self.getPageList, a_method=locals().items())
```